# RaiseEvent with Ternary Operator

Tags: vb.net, events

I expected the following to work:

```
RaiseEvent If(condition, event, event)
```

But the compiler complains about it:

> Error BC30676: "If" is not an event of ...

How to realize a Ternary Operator Statement with `RaiseEvents`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [syntax for `RaiseEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed.aspx):

> ```
> RaiseEvent eventname[( argumentlist )]
> ```

It's not that `RaiseEvent` just accepts any arbitrary expression - you *have* to specify the name of an event. You'll just need to use a regular `If` statement:

```
If condition Then
    RaiseEvent event1
Else
    RaiseEvent event2
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that which is why you're getting the error.  Just do this instead:

```
If (condition) Then RaiseEvent eventA Else RaiseEvent eventB
```